# Nested INNER JOIN within LEFT JOIN in SAS

Tags: sql, join, sas, nested

I would REALLY appreciate your help with this problem I am having. I am not a SAS developer (Oracle SQL is my gig) so I am hoping you genius's out there can help me :)
I have executed the following code in SQL Developer and it produces the results I require; Providers with or without specialties and only specialties where the source is <> to 'NA'. I have tried several other ways of only getting the results I require and this is the only code that accomplishes it (so far).
However, When I run this in SAS it gives an error after the LEFT JOIN and "Sub" INNER JOIN - SAS says it was expecting a "ON".

```
INNER JOIN schemaA.providers prov
        ON claims.prov_key = prov.prov_key 
 LEFT JOIN schemaA.specialties spec
     INNER JOIN schemaA.source src
             ON spec.src_key = src.src_key
            AND src.src_cd <> 'NA'
       ON prov.prov_key = spec.prov_key
```

Comment: Can you post the full query?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. An error message is almost certainly a faq.  Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

SAS is probably smarter about its `JOIN` syntax.  The above is standard SQL and allowed.  But I highly discourage it.  You can try using parentheses:

```
INNER JOIN
schemaA.providers prov
ON claims.prov_key = prov.prov_key LEFT JOIN
(schemaA.specialties spec INNER JOIN
 schemaA.source src
 ON spec.src_key = src.src_key AND src.src_cd <> 'NA'
)
ON prov.prov_key = spec.prov_key
```

This might help the parser.  Otherwise, this probably does what you want:

```
INNER JOIN
schemaA.providers prov
ON claims.prov_key = prov.prov_key LEFT JOIN
schemaA.specialties spec
ON prov.prov_key = spec.prov_key LEFT JOIN
schemaA.source src
ON spec.src_key = src.src_key AND src.src_cd <> 'NA'
```

This version is certainly easier for people to parse.  It should also be easier for the SAS processor to parse as well.

Note:  This version is not *exactly* the same as your version.  Notably it handles missing matches in `spec` and `src` a bit differently.  However, my guess is that it is functionally equivalent on your data.

EDIT:

An exact match to the logic would be:

```
INNER JOIN
schemaA.providers prov
ON claims.prov_key = prov.prov_key LEFT JOIN
(SELECT spe.prov_key, . . .  -- list the columns you want here
 FROM schemaA.specialties spec INNER JOIN
      schemaA.source src
      ON spec.src_key = src.src_key AND src.src_cd <> 'NA'
) spec
ON prov.prov_key = spec.prov_key
```

Comment: That will not work you have to add an SELECT ... FROM after the opening parentheses

Comment: @Lee . . . It works in other databases.  I don't know if `proc sql` allows it or not -- which is why I suggested it.

Comment: Ok you are right with parentheses it works at least in SAS 9.4

Comment: You need the () to avoid the error about missing ON.  Note that the code generate by the FEEDBACK option of PROC SQL actually does NOT include the (), and so the code it generates does not work with PROC SQL.